# Select from a list

Tags: javascript

What i want to achieve is similar to what you get when you are donating money, I want the user to pick the amount from a list and then the amount appears in the text input, so how is this done with javascript

html is below:

```
<div id="container">
        <ul>
        <li id="one"><a href="">$14</a> </li>
        <li id="two"><a href="">$25</a></li>
        <li id="three"><a href="">$36</a></li>
        <li id="four"><a href="">$40</a></li>
        <li id="five"><a href="">$200</a></li>
    </ul>

        <form method="post" action="" class="forms">
    <label>
        Amount Donated
        <input id="value" type="text" name="amount" class="width-10" />
    </label>
 </form> 
</div>
```

javascript below:

```
var amountClicked = document.getElementById("one");

if (amountClicked.clicked == true) {

    document.getElementById("value").value = "$14";

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected value of dropdownlist using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

Comment: what is "clicked" in `amountClicked.clicked`?

Comment: You should add amounts in option of <select> and then add a change event for this to change amount inputs value

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="currency" onchange="myFunction()">
 <option value="14">$14</option >
 <option value="25">$25</option >
 <option value="36">$36</option >
 <option value="40">$40</option >
<select>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("currency").value;
    document.getElementById("value").value =x;
}
</script>
```